# Python Dictionary: compare 2 values in 1 key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

I have a dataset where there is a list of names in a column, and a response for each name in a separate column. Each name is listed twice, and I want to see if there is agreement between the two recorded responses. 
i.e.

name a | response 1

name a | response 2

name b | response 1

name b | response 2

I created a dictionary where the key has two values. The dictionary creates the name as the key, and each response as a value. I want to create a list to see if response1 = response2, or if response1 != response2. Here is what I have so far:

```
myDict = {}
if name not in myDict.keys():
    myDict[name] = {'response1': answer}
else:
    myDict[name]['reponse2'] = answer

match = True
for items in hospitalDict:
    if hospitalDict[items] != hospitalDict[items]:
          match = False
print match
```

I am stuck on this part...any advice on how to construct this? I would also like to output this data to a csv eventually.

Comment: Why not just use two separate dictionaries response_1_dict and response_2_dict and do your comparisons that way?

Comment: create a dictionary with names as keys, and add values as a set.  If the set size is 1 they are equal.  Else size will be two

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to achieve is a list of names that have matching answers.

given that you have the dictionary already created:

```
myDict = {
    'name 1' : {'response1':'A', 'response2':'B'},
    'name 2' : {'response1':'C', 'response2':'C'},
    ... ,
    'name N' : {'response1':'Z', 'response2':'Z'},
}
```

you could do the following:

```
myList = []
for name, resp in myDict:
    if resp['response1'] == resp['response2']:
        myList.append(name)
print myList
```

the result should be something like:

```
['name 2', ..., 'name N']
```

that list only includes names with matching answers

Comment: `[name for name, resp in myDict if resp['response1'] == resp['response2']]`

Comment: @torresmateo When I try this method, i get KeyError: 'response2', any idea why?

Comment: @KaraSewalk check your code, your dict key is "reponse2" not "response2"

Answer (score 0):

I implemented NamesDict class, which could have 2 or more responses for each key (name), compare it and export. To export in csv you can easily use csv library for python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

I put comparison and csv export functions as an example.

```
import csv


class NamesDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NamesDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            self.__dict__[key] = item
        else:
            raise Exception('item has to be a dict')

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]

    def responses_match(self, key):
        # Here you can implement your own comparison method
        match = False
        for key_one, value_one in self.__dict__[key].items():
            for key_two, value_two in self.__dict__[key].items():
                if key_one != key_two and value_one == value_two:
                    match = True
        return match

    def export_csv(self, path):
        # Here you can change csv export
        with open(path, 'wb') as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['name', 'responses']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
                responses_string = ''
                for resp_key, resp in value.items():
                    responses_string += '%s=%s\n' % (str(resp_key), str(resp_key))

                writer.writerow({
                    'name': key,
                    'responses': responses_string
                })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    namesDict = NamesDict()
    namesDict['test'] = {
        'response1': 1,
        'response2': 2
    }

    namesDict['test2'] = {
        'response1': 2,
        'response2': 2
    }

    print(namesDict.responses_match('test'))    # False
    print(namesDict.responses_match('test2'))   # True

    namesDict.export_csv('test.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupby and customer key function to separate two groups

```
   from itertools import groupby
   myDict = {
        'name 1' : {'response1':'A', 'response2':'B'},
        'name 2' : {'response1':'C', 'response2':'C'},
        'name N' : {'response1':'Z', 'response2':'Z'},
    }

    for i in groupby(myDict.items(),key = lambda x: x[1]['response1'] == x[1]['response2']):
        print i[0],list(i[1])

    True [('name N', {'response2': 'Z', 'response1': 'Z'}), ('name 2', {'response2': 'C', 'response1': 'C'})]
    False [('name 1', {'response2': 'B', 'response1': 'A'})]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming myDict and hospitalDict are the same dictionary, you need just one simple change.   Change the line:

```
if hospitalDict[items] != hospitalDict[items]:
```

To the line:

```
if hospitalDict[items]["response1"] != hospitalDict[items]["response2"]:
```

Then **match** will be True if all the responses match, and False if there are one or more different responses.

Comment: When I try this method, I get: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is a list in the following form:

```
input_data = [
    [ "bob", "okay" ],
    [ "bob", "okay" ],
    [ "tom", "yes" ],
    [ "tom", "no" ],
    [ "kim", "red" ],
    [ "kim", "blue" ],
    [ "kim", "red" ],
    [ "kim", "green" ],
    [ "kim", "blue" ],
]
```

You can process it as follows:

```
myDict = {}

for name, answer in input_data:
    myDict.setdefault(name, set()).add(answer)

print "The following names had differing responses"

for name, answers in myDict.items():
    if len(answers) > 1:
        print name, list(answers)
```

This code snippet produces the output:

```
The following names had differing responses
kim ['blue', 'green', 'red']
tom ['yes', 'no']
```